# How to smooth a circular plot?

Tags: r, plot, signal-processing, cycle, smoothing

```
x <- sin(1:20)
y <- (dplyr::lag(x)-x)-x
plot(x, y, type="l")
```

Yields this plot:

[image]

How do I get a smooth, cyclical trajectory? The smoothing functions I've tried all want to make a single smooth function.

Example 1 (throws an error):

```
lines(smooth.spline(x, y))
```

Example 2 (draws a function):

```
lo <- loess(y~x)
lines(predict(lo), col='red', lwd=2)
```

Example 3 (draws a function):

```
xspline(c(x,y), shape=1, border='blue' )
```

Comment: *"every smoothing function I've tried"* ... can you provide an example of one you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for both (a) smoother curves and (b) cylindrical/symmetric circles, correct?

Increase the count of points to make it smoother.  Fix the aspect ratio to make it a circle (*i.e.*, `asp=1`).

```
x <- sin((1:20000) / 1000)
y <- cos((1:20000) / 1000)
plot(x, y, type="l", asp=1)
```

[image]

*EDIT, responding to OP's comments below.*:

This uses `dplyr::lag()`, while increasing the number of points.  Don't conceptually shift the lag though (*i.e.*, *y* should be a full value of `1` from *x*).

(*x*=1, *y*=0), (*x*=1.001, *y*=0.001), ..., (*x*=20, *y*=19)

```
x <- sin((1:20000) / 1000)
y <- (dplyr::lag(x, 1000)-x)-x
plot(x, y, type="l", asp=1)
```

[image]

If that's not what you want, maybe sketch a picture and attach in (in like MS Paint or Inkscape).

Comment: The goal is to create a plot that is smoother than its trajectory, not to just draw ovals. I.e., I have a trajectory I want to plot (that isn't this toy data), and I want to draw it as a smooth, cyclical trajectory. I also want to preserve the asymmetry.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: x is fixed; it is data I collected from a human participant, so I cannot change the number of points because it was determined by the sampling rate of my equipment. So, given a vector x, how can I plot its trajectory as smooth trajectory? I want to visualize existing data rather than draw a certain picture.

Comment: @PhiloT Please add _relevant_ (minimal) data to your post.

Comment: I'd like to see representative data, as well as a sketch of how you'd like it to look.   Similar to sketching it on a napkin at dinner to demonstrate a rough idea.  I can't tell if you want something simple that ggplot's `coord_polar()` can do, or if you need to roll your own interpolation, [like the polar graphs in this article](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/Wats/blob/master/UtilityScripts/Handouts.md#figure-5-polar-periodic).